# Unable to navigate to a destination in other graph

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

Using Android Navigation component in our code with SAMF (Single Activity, Multiple Fragments) approach for each functionality. Say each functionality will have own navigation graph intended to navigate between them.

e.g., the graphs are *graph_a*, *graph_b*, *graph_c* with its own fragments and designed to navigate as below:

```
  graph_a >> graph_b >> graph_c
```

and it works as expected. 
Now, there are scenarios where a Fragment(frag_b) might need to navigate another one in different navigation graph like

```
  frag_b(graph_b) >> frag_c(graph_a)
```

I found the optimal solution, in this case, could be navigate using URI and tried below.

```
  val deepLink = Uri.parse("app://login/user-signup")
  findNavController().navigate(deepLink)
```

and added the following *deeplink* for to be called fragment in the respective graph.

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/graph_login_flow"
    app:startDestination="@id/userSignInFragment">
    ...
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/userSignUpFragment"
        android:name="com.app.login.ui.UserSignUpFragment"
        android:label="EmailSignUpFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_user_sign_up">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_userSiUpFrag_to_emailVeriFrag"
            app:destination="@id/emailVerificationFragment" />
        <deepLink
            android:id="@+id/deepLink_to_userSignUpFragment"
            app:uri="app://login/user-signup" />
    </fragment>
    <include app:graph="@navigation/graph_home_flow" />
    ...
</navigation>
```

As per Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#uri), can navigate to any destination regardless of graphs but my attempt results in the following error. 
Is there any better approach?

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination with deepLink app://login/user-signup is unknown to this NavController
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:916)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:894)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:880)
    at com.app.home.profile.ProfileFragment.onViewCreated(ProfileFragment.kt:82)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:298)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1232)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2390)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2125)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2081)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1977)
```

Comment: Your deep link says `gastgo://`, but your URI says `app://`. Those would have to match, right?

Comment: corrected the comment

Comment: Can you include some more context on where your `<deepLink>` is in your navigation graph file? `<deepLink>` elements don't have an `android:id`, they're attached to an individual destination.

Comment: Sure, added `<deepLink>` in the destination graph beneath targetted fragment. Regarding id, I followed the https://www.raywenderlich.com/4332831-navigation-component-for-android-part-2-graphs-and-deep-links

Comment: I was asking for you to include a larger snippet of your navigation graph in your question.

Comment: @ianhanniballake, the question updated with the navigation graph, Fragment it's and attributes such `action` and `deepLink`. Hope it would help, Thanks.

Comment: Is the error message really `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination with deepLink  is unknown to this NavController`? The Uri should be printed in that error message

Comment: Yes, the exception is as you said with deepLink and Uri. The question updated with detailed exception form Studio console.

Comment: Can you share your top-most nav graph? If you modularize it, they have to be bound together at the top-most nav graph. That's how they would be visible together.

Comment: Hi, it's same as in the question whereas the deeplink Uri ("app://login/user-signup") is called from another graph.

Comment: Can you please clarify what's meant by bound together. In my scenario, the deeplink is calling from `home_graph` and the called Fragment(with deeplink) is in `login_graph` where the `login_graph` is already included `home_graph` as it's continuous.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Took a holiday break. Anyway, shouldn't it be the other way around? `home_graph` should include `login_graph`

Comment: To clarify, my flow is from login >> home. So, login_graph includes the home_graph as a nested graph. including vice-versa would not serve the purpose. please guide :)